# Failed to update vendor deps via godep update ... command and godep save -r ./

Tags: go, godeps

I have latest deps available in my $GOPATH. Now i want to update my project Godeps.json with new deps(with latest GOPATH) by calling `godep update ./...` and then calling `godep save ./...` . 
however still I am with old deps in Godeps.json .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have git committed package you want to update, you can check the commit sha-1 checksum using git log and make sure it has different rev commit version in Godeps.json.
Then include package name in godep command `godep update github.com/package/...`

Comment: Thanks Rohardjo. This was exactly the problem. I overlooked git stuff while reading the doc of terrraform. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out [difference between godep update and godep save](https://blog.codeship.com/godep-dependency-management-in-golang/).
I usually just use `godep save` unless I am updating a specific package. This grabs all the updated packages for the project from `GOPATH`. 
BTW: I am also fairly new to Godeps.

Comment: Thanks @sthe . I tried godep save also however its coming with same result

Comment: No no error. Now i think the answer given by Rohardjo looks logical and this is how doc of hashicorp says. I am trying it will update again here. Thanks

Comment: I see. Let us know how it goes :-)